# Make more room in the bitmap in android

Tags: android

What is the best way to make more room (increase width of the bitmap) in the bitmap without distorting or scaling the existing data in Android. I'm tried various method and still can't figure out how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [Nine-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) image with [Draw 9 Patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) tool

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty bitmap which is wider than your existing one, and draw the original bitmap onto the empty bitmap,

Comment: Could you describe how to draw one bitmap on other?